# null value when using Dojo datagrid formatter function

Tags: django-templates, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to use a formatter to format dates in a dojo grid with DOJANGO.

This is the template script:

```
{% extends "dojango/base.html" %}
{% load dojango_grid %}

{% block dojango_page_title %} Testing datagrid {% endblock %}

{% block dojango_header_extra %}

<script type="text/javascript">
function formatDate(datum) {
    var d = dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString(datum);
    return dojo.date.locale.format(d, {formatLength: 'long'});
}
</script>

<script>
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dojo.date.stamp");
dojo.require("dojo.date.locale");

</script>

{% endblock %}

{% block dojango_content %}
<h1> Movimientos </h1>
</br>
</br>

{% datagrid voucher_v1 Movimiento %}
    width="100%"
    height="500px"
   formatter=     {'fecha_cambio_saldo':"this.formatDate",'fecha_cambio_saldo_anterior':"this.formatDate"}
    id="test_grid"
{% enddatagrid %}

{% endblock %}
```

However, the function parameter `datum` is passed null and there is an exception at the line:

```
return dojo.date.locale.format(d, {formatLength: 'long'});
```

(it complains that `ObjectDate.getHours()` is undefined since ObjectDate is null)

What am I missing something here? I followed the example from [this link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#formatting-a-date-field):

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the script

```
function formatDate(datum) {
    var d = dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString(datum);
    return dojo.date.locale.format(d, {formatLength: 'long'});
}
```

after the dojo requires statements

Comment: Tried that and didn't work either.   <br/>Anyways, I quit dojo and used django tables instead. It works beautiful.